# SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers returns No recognizer installed

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am trying to get a simple speech recognition program started but it does not work, I've installed some languages (en-GB & en-US) but whenever I use the following:

> SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers

it returns an empty collection. Even when I just try to start a recognizer it will return "*no recognizer installed*". But when I reinstall a language, it says that it is already installed.

```
using ( SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")))
{
    // Create and load a dictation grammar.
    recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());

    // Add a handler for the speech recognized event.
    recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
      new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

    // Configure input to the speech recognizer.
    recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    // Start asynchronous, continuous speech recognition.
    recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    // Keep the console window open.
    while (true)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

For what reason is it unable to find the installed recognizers?

Edit:

This is the exception: {System.ArgumentException: No recognizer of the required ID found.
Parameter name: culture
   at System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine..ctor(CultureInfo culture)

and: `var recognizers = SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers();` returns a collection with a count of 0

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you call `SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers`.  Can you post the code you're actually using, and the full text of the exception that's thrown?

Comment: @ Dan Puzey, ive used the SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers(); only for checking what was installed, i dont use it in the actual code

Comment: So this would be the case regardless of the code that you've listed in the question?  I can run that line alone in LinqPad and get a result - it seems that the code you've posted originally isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Based on [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdkaudioapi/thread/f59848eb-decb-4eae-9248-d103bdd81dca/) it seems that there may be some incompatbility between `Microsoft.Speech` and `System.Speech` namespaces.  How are you installing your languages, and which namespace are you using?  There's also a potential 32/64-bit incompatibility.

Comment: Yes it is relevant, quote: "Even when I just try to start a recognizer" the starting of the recognizer engine is what i posted there.

Comment: ive donwloaded 'MSSpeech_SR_en-GB_TELE.msi' from the microsoft website, and i ame using System.Speech.Recognition; i ame running it on a x86 computer.

Comment: Try going to Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Speech Recognition -> Advanced Speech Options and ensure that the `Language` toolbar at the top has a recognizer set. If not, set one, click OK, and then try again. Also note that `Microsoft.Speech` language packs are not the same as `System.Speech` ones.

Comment: It finds more then one recognizer now, i ame now using microsoft.speech.recognition. but now when i try to load grammar, it says: The language for the grammar does not match the language of the speech recognizer. whay is this? i ame using the example on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I installed language packs that can be accessed by `Microsoft.Speech` and I was using `System.Speech`, when I switched to  `Microsoft.Speech` it worked.

Comment: @[Profile not found] Could you please share where you got the Microsoft.Speech language packs? I'm unable to find them. I have English (United States) language installed on my computer, but SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")) still fails.

Comment: For people who have the same problem as the person above: Downloading language packs for Microsoft Speech can be done here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224