# Using foreign language with System.Speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm trying to use System.Speech or Mircosoft.Speech with Norwegian Language. I have downloaded and installed both "SR_MS_nb-NO_TELE_11.0" and "TTS_MS_nb-NO_Hulda_11.0". But when trying to initialize:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine recognize = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nb-NO"));
```

I get unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Speech.dll.
I tried printing the installed voices and it results in only Microsoft Anna. How do I "enable/activate" the downloaded language?

Comment: Do you get the stack trace? This is a pretty vague error message.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it's relevant. The issue is how to either import the language files or how to activate them. The problem is that it can't find the ID "nb-NO". (Message=No recognizer of the required ID found.) The languages are installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Speech\Tokens

Comment: This may be related. Hard to say. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856798/speech-recognition-c-sharp

Comment: Which SR library are you linking with?   Microsoft.Speech.Recognition or System.Speech.Recognition?