# Voice recognition not working properly

Tags: vb.net

Can you help me? This code below have a stranger warning/error when launching. I get a message like "no recognizer is installed". What should I do? I'm already running it as x86 CPU.

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Speech
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports System.Speech.Recognition.SrgsGrammar

Public Class Form1

Dim WithEvents reco As New SpeechRecognitionEngine
Dim synth As New Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try

        Dim gram As New SrgsDocument
        Dim colorRule As New SrgsRule("color")
        Dim colorsList As New SrgsOneOf("red", "green")

        colorRule.Add(colorsList)
        gram.Rules.Add(colorRule)
        gram.Root = colorRule
        reco.LoadGrammarAsync(New Recognition.Grammar(gram))
        reco.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
        reco.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)

    Catch s As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(s.Message)
    End Try


End Sub

Private Sub reco_SpeechDetected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechDetectedEventArgs) Handles reco.SpeechDetected
    Label1.Text = "Voz detectada"
End Sub

Private Sub reco_SpeechRecognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionEventArgs) Handles reco.SpeechRecognized
    Select Case e.Result.Text
        Case "vermelho"
            SetColor(Color.Red)
        Case "verde"
            SetColor(Color.Lime)
    End Select
End Sub


Private Sub SetColor(ByVal color As System.Drawing.Color)
    reco.RecognizeAsyncCancel()
    reco.RecognizeAsyncStop()
    synth.Speak("mudando cor para " & color.ToString)
    Me.BackColor = color
    reco.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)
End Sub
End Class
```

P.S.: I'm running my Windows 7 in Portuguese, there's any problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers returns No recognizer installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856798/speechrecognitionengine-installedrecognizers-returns-no-recognizer-installed)

Comment: I saw this thread, but unfortunately the solution did not work for me

Comment: In Windows 7, you have to install [Microsoft Speech Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361572(v=office.14).aspx). Install the SDK (for development), the Runtime (for distribution) and all relevant voices (Portuguese is included - Portugal and Brazil). Your assembly will be `Microsoft.Speech` (not `System.Speech`). The SDK includes a Grammar Builder/Validator.