# Fail to set up English to SpeechRecognitionEngine

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

Hi Currently I'm trying to do a simple Voice Recognition but when I try to do this:

```
 SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine;
 var language = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
 recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(language); //Crashes here.
 recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
 var _dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
 recEngine.LoadGrammar(_dictationGrammar);
 recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_ListenEvent;
```

It crashes because of : 'No recognizer of the required ID found.
Parameter name: culture'

What I got as usings are:

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Globalization;
```

Any Idea?
What I think is that I need to install the recognition language but is there a way to do so in code?

Comment: I believe, this is due to `CultureInfo`, which should be "<lang>-<country>", so in your case "en-US"/"en-UK"/"en-GB"/"en-AU". (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation)

Comment: Also tried with "en-US" and doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: According to this question, you have to switch from the System.Speech.* package to Microsoft.Speech.*. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856798/speechrecognitionengine-installedrecognizers-returns-no-recognizer-installed)

Comment: I tried that and Microsoft.Speech Does not exist in my assemblies.